How to capitalize only the FIGURE + figure number in figure titles
I want to only capitalize the figure title as "FIGURE I". I have the below code on Figures.
Any help would be appreciated
\usepackage[font=bf]{caption}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\Roman{figure}}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
    \caption{\textbf{ \newline Countries}}
                    
    \includegraphics[width=0.80\textwidth, height=0.25\textheight]{Figures/countries}
    \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
        \footnotesize 
    \end{minipage}
    \label{fig:Map}
\end{figure} 


As always on this sire please please provide a full but minimal example others can copy and test as is. You can safely use the images listed here: https://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/mwe as we do not have the image you use. You might find this tedious, but from what you have provided here we have no idea about your setup, which packages you are using or which document class.

You wrote

I want to only capitalize the figure title as "FIGURE I"

Since you've already figured out how to use uppercase-roman numerals to enumerate the figure environments, I guessing that you're looking for the instruction
\renewcommand{\figurename}{FIGURE}



\documentclass[demo]{article} % remove 'demo' option in real document
\usepackage{graphicx} 

\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\Roman{figure}}
\renewcommand{\figurename}{FIGURE} % <-- new
\usepackage[font=bf,labelsep=newline]{caption}

\begin{document}    

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
    \caption{Countries}\label{fig:Map} 
    \includegraphics[width=0.80\textwidth, height=0.25\textheight]{Figures/countries}
%    \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
%        \footnotesize 
%    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\end{document}


Perfect! Thanks very very much!
